# Type error on the function passed to Dict.map

Tags: dictionary, functional-programming, elm

I am reletively new to functional programming, to be honest about 2 days. I am trying to print out values from a `Dict Int Int`, but I can't seem to figure out how to pass this `Dict Int Int` to a function.

The error I am receiving is below.

> The 1st argument to `map` is not what I expect:
>
> 32|   div [] (Dict.map toLiDict dict)
>                          ^^^^^^^^ This `toLiDict` value is a:
>
> ```
> Dict Int Int -> Html msg
> ```
>
> But `map` needs the 1st argument to be:
>
> ```
> Dict Int Int -> b
> ```

The function `toHtmlDict` and `toLiDict` is the one's causing me this issue, they are currently commented out below. Also I am calling this from the view, `div [] [ toHtmlDict model.uniqueValues ]`, I have this commented out as well.

Here is what I am currently working with; I posted the whole code as it would be easier if you should need anything else.

Here's a link on Ellie [here](https://ellie-app.com/5D2MnHdR7fga1) that can be ran.

```
module Main exposing (main)

import Browser
import Dict exposing (Dict)
import Html.Attributes
import Html exposing (Html, button, div, text, strong, p, li, ul)
import Html.Events exposing (onClick)

type alias Model =
    { currentNumber : Int, clicks : Int, outputList : List(String), uniqueValues : Dict Int Int }
    --{ currentNumber : Int, clicks : Int, history : String, outputList : List(String) }

initialModel : Model
initialModel =
    { currentNumber = 0, clicks = 0, outputList = [""], uniqueValues = Dict.fromList [(1,1)] } --Dict.empty should be default here...
    --{ currentNumber = 0, clicks = 0, history = "Current outputs ...", outputList = ["Current outputs ...", " "] }

-- applies a new div for each element in the list
toHtmlList : List String -> Html msg
toHtmlList strings =
  div [] (List.map toLi strings)

-- creates a div along with the text to be shown
toLi : String -> Html msg
toLi s = 
  div [] [ text s ]

-- --applies a new div for each element in the dictionary
-- toHtmlDict : Dict Int Int -> Html msg
-- toHtmlDict dict =
--   div [] (Dict.map toLiDict dict)

-- -- creates a div along with the text to be shown
-- toLiDict : Dict Int Int  -> Html msg
-- toLiDict k = 
--   div [] [ text "What here?" ]

type Msg
    = Increment
    | Decrement

update : Msg -> Model -> Model
update msg model =
    case msg of
    -- Note: when assigning the model.currentNumber and then concatenating the value, it will not be updated...
        Increment ->
            { model | currentNumber = model.currentNumber + 1, clicks = model.clicks + 1, outputList = model.outputList ++ [addToPage (oddOrEven(model.currentNumber + 1)) (model.currentNumber + 1)], uniqueValues = model.uniqueValues }
            --{ model | currentNumber = model.currentNumber + 1, clicks = model.clicks + 1, history = model.history ++ addToPage (oddOrEven(model.currentNumber + 1)) (model.currentNumber + 1), outputList = model.outputList ++ [addToPage (oddOrEven(model.currentNumber + 1)) (model.currentNumber + 1)] }

        Decrement ->
            { model | currentNumber = model.currentNumber - 1, clicks = model.clicks + 1, outputList = model.outputList ++ [addToPage (oddOrEven(model.currentNumber - 1)) (model.currentNumber - 1)]}
            --{ model | currentNumber = model.currentNumber - 1, clicks = model.clicks + 1, history = model.history ++ addToPage (oddOrEven(model.currentNumber - 1)) (model.currentNumber - 1), outputList = model.outputList ++ [addToPage (oddOrEven(model.currentNumber - 1)) (model.currentNumber - 1)]}

view : Model -> Html Msg
view model =
    Html.div []    
        [ button [ onClick Increment ] [ strong [Html.Attributes.style "color" "black"] [ text "+1" ]]     
        , button [ onClick Decrement ] [ strong [Html.Attributes.style "color" "red"] [ text "-1" ]]
        , p [] []      
        --, div [] [ text <| "The current number is: ",  strong [Html.Attributes.style "color" "red"] [ text <| String.fromInt model.currentNumber ], text " and it's ", text (oddOrEven model.currentNumber) ]
        , div [] [ text <| "The current number is: ",  strong [Html.Attributes.style "color" <| evenOddColor model.currentNumber] [ text <| String.fromInt model.currentNumber ], text " and it's ", strong [Html.Attributes.style "color" <| evenOddColor model.currentNumber ] [ text <| oddOrEven model.currentNumber ] ]          
        , div [] [ text "Total clicks: ",  strong [Html.Attributes.style "color" "red"] [ text <| String.fromInt model.clicks ]] 
        , p [] []
        , div [] [ strong [Html.Attributes.style "color" "Blue"] [ text "Unique values ..." ]]          
        , p [] []
        --, div [] [ toHtmlDict model.uniqueValues ]
        --, div [] [ text <| "The current number is: " ++ String.fromInt model.currentNumber ++ " and it's " ++  oddOrEven model.currentNumber ]        
        --, div [] [ text "Total clicks: ",  strong [Html.Attributes.style "color" "red"] [ text <| String.fromInt model.clicks ]] 
        --, p [] [] 
        , div [] [ strong [Html.Attributes.style "color" "Blue"] [ text "History ..." ]]    
        , p [] []     
        --, div [] [ text <| model.history ] - TEMPORARY        
        , div [] [ toHtmlList model.outputList ]

        ]

-- appendToList string number =
--     "Number was " ++ String.fromInt number ++ " and it was " ++ string 

addToPage string number =     
    "Number was " ++ String.fromInt number ++ " and it was " ++ string           

-- determines if number is even or odd        
oddOrEven number =
 if modBy 2 number == 0 then
     "even" 
 else
    "odd"

-- call another function with param
evenOddColor number =
 if oddOrEven(number) == "even" then
    "green"
 else
    "red"

main : Program () Model Msg
main =
    Browser.sandbox
        { init = initialModel
        , view = view
        , update = update
        }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Dict.map` is a function that will transform the values of a `Dict` and return another `Dict` with the new values. This is not what you want here, but lets try to grok its type anyway, because it's a useful learning experience.

#### Dict.map

A `Dict`s full type is `Dick k v`, meaning that the type variables correspond to the type of its keys and values respectively. `Dict.map`, according to [the documentation](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/core/latest/Dict#map), has the type `(k -> a -> b) -> Dict k a -> Dict k b`. As its first argument it takes a function of two arguments, `k` and `a`, and that returns a `b`. `map`s second argument is a `Dict k a`, and it returns a `Dict k b`.

We can see that the `k` is the same in both the input and return `Dict`s, which means its type will remain the same, but the type variable for the values is different, `a` in the input and `b` in the return `Dict`. And the function similarly takes `a` as one of its inputs, along with a `k`, and returns a `b`. So for each of the key-value pairs in the input `Dict`, the mapping function will be called with its key, 'k', and value 'a', and is expected to return a `b` value.

For a `Dict Int Int` as you have, both `k` and `v` are `Int`s. If we substitute these in the type of `Dict.map` we get `(Int -> Int -> b) -> Dict Int Int -> Dict Int b`. We don't know what `b` is yet since that will be determined by the function we pass it, but we can at least see that the function expects two `Int` arguments`.

Meanwhile, the function you give it, `toLiDict`, has the type `Dict Int Int -> Html msg` which takes one argument that isn't an `Int`. This is what the error message is clumsily trying to convey. We could rewrite `toLiDict` to conform to what `Dict.map` expects, as a function `Int -> Int -> Html msg`, but that would have `Dict.map` return a `Dict Int (Html msg)`, which isn't what you want. So let's drop that.

In general, `map` functions conventionally transform the elements of a collection without changing the type of collection.

### Dict.foldl

If you want instead is to transform the elements of a collection into something else entirely, and there isn't something more specific to use, a "fold" is usually the right tool. `Dict` provides `foldl` and `foldr`, which basically does the same thing but in different order, `foldl` iterates over the elements from the "left" and `foldr` from the "right". If the order doesn't matter, use `foldl` because it's more efficient.

The type signature of `Dict.foldl` is `(k -> v -> b -> b) -> b -> Dict k v -> b`. That is, the transformation function now takes three arguments, the key, `k`, value, `v`, and a `b` which we'll call the accumulator, and returns a `b`. `foldl` itself also takes an additional argument, again a `b`, which will be the initial `b` value passed to the transformation function. The third argument is the `Dict`, and the return value is again a `b`.

For each key-value pair in the input `Dict`, `foldl` will, just like `map`, call the transformation function with its key and value. But it also provides a `b` which initially is the `b` value passed to `foldl` itself, but for subsequent iterations will be the `b` value returned from the transformation function. In that way the "accumulator" accumulates the return value.

Let's rewrite your code to use `Dict.foldl` instead:

```
toHtmlDict : Dict Int Int -> Html msg
toHtmlDict dict =
  div [] (Dict.foldl toLiDict [] dict)

toLiDict : Int -> Int -> List (Html msg) -> List (Html msg)
toLiDict k v acc = 
  div [] [ text "What here?" ] :: acc
```

Here, `toHtmlDict` remains largely the same, but uses `Dict.foldl` instead of `Dict.map` and provides it an initial value of an empty list, `[]`.

`toLiDict` sees bigger changes. Its type has changed to `Int -> Int -> List (Html msg) -> List (Html msg)`, mneaning it takes the arguments: The key and value, both of which are `Int`s, and the accumulator is a `List (Html msg)`, as is the return value.

But the implementation has barely changed. Instead of just returning an element directly, it's appended to the accumulator with `:: acc`.

And that's all there is to it. The result of the fold is the accumulated list of `Html` elements, as expected. If you plop the above code into yours, it will work.

#### Dict.values and Dict.toList

Finally, I noted earlier that `foldl` is a good choice if there aren't more appropriate specialized function. And since the end result you want is a list, either `Dict.values` or `Dict.toList`, as @bdukes has suggested, probably are. These aren't as efficient as a fold, since you'll iterate trough the elements twice, once to convert to a list and then to map them, but this rarely matters in practice. Specialized functions are also more descriptive and documents your intent better, so use them if you can.

Comment: Thank you so much for the very detailed answer, just what I needed! I tried both solutions and they both work great. I hope to get a better grasp on this sooner, only been 2 days into learning elm... Thanks for the edit as well :)

Answer (score 3):

The definition of [`Dict.map`](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/core/latest/Dict#map) is `(k -> a -> b) -> Dict k a -> Dict k b`.  So it takes a function and a `Dict` and returns a new `Dict`.  That mapping function takes the key and value, and returns a new value.

In your case, you're looking to return a `List (Html Msg)`, rather than a `Dict` of anything.  So, rather than using `Dict.map`, I would call [`Dict.values`](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/core/latest/Dict#values) to get a `List` of the values, and then use `List.map` to transform those values into `Html Msg`.  If you need both the key and value to generate the `Html Msg`, use [`Dict.toList`](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/core/latest/Dict#toList) instead, to get a `List (k, v)` (i.e. a `List` of tuples, where the tuple has the key and value).

```
toHtmlDict : Dict Int Int -> Html Msg
toHtmlDict dict =
    div [] (List.map viewDictEntry (Dict.toList dict))

viewDictEntry : (Int, Int) -> Html Msg
viewDictEntry (key, value) =
    li [] [ text (String.fromInt key), text " = ", text (String.fromInt value) ]
```

Comment: Alright, makes sense. Although I am recieving an error: `The argument is a pattern that matches tuples of type:

    ( a, b )

But the type annotation on 'viewDictEntry' says the 1st argument should be:

    List ( Int, Int )

Hint: Did you forget to add [] around it?`

Comment: Did you change `Dict.map` to `List.map`?

Comment: @glennsl sure did.

Comment: Oh, the type annotation of `viewDictEntry` is just wrong. I took the liberty of removing the superfluous `List` from it

Comment: @glennsl yes, just seen this! Thanks appreciate the help. bdukes thanks for the fast response and explanation, still new to this functional programming!